# Django : Two Models from Separate Databases

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django; I have a legacy database I do not control with some information regarding a user and a database on my server with data pertaining to something that user is doing.  I want to take some information from each database via the ORM methodology Django employs and display it on a webform, but I am struggling.  I search on the patient id and can find what codes they have associated with them, but when it comes to displaying the cost for each code with the associated data, I do not know the best way to do so.  I am not saving this data at the moment.

(my database)

```
class Data(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    cost = models.FloatField()
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

(legacy)

```
class UserHistory(models.Model)
   userid= models.IntegerField(db_column='userid', blank=True, null=True) 
   code = models.CharField(db_column='code', max_length=11, blank=True)
   firstname = models.CharField(db_column='FirstName', max_length=35, blank=True) 
   middlename = models.CharField(db_column='MiddleName', max_length=35, blank=True) 
   lastname = models.CharField(db_column='LastName', max_length=35, blank=True)
```

Desired Output:

Here is the cost for user First Name Last Name

```
Last Name |  First Name |    Code  |  Cost
----------+-------------+----------+--------
xxx       |     zzzzz   |       2  |  10.00
xxx       |     zzzzz   |       6  |  10.00
xxx       |     zzzzz   |       7  |  10.00
xxx       |     zzzzz   |      11  |  10.00
```

Answer (score 2):

It's in Django Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/, in particular you may create [two querysets from different databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset).

You have to get the results from the first queryset, [export them as a list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) and use that list to query the second database ([using the `in` operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)).

**example**:

```
 user = UserHistory.objects.using('legacy').filter(firstname='John', lastname='Doe')
 codes = list(users.values_list('code', flat=True))
 costs = Data.objects.using('default').filter(code__in=codes)
```

you may use aggregation (`Sum` for instance) or pass directly the `costs` queryset to your RequestContext.

EDIT:
the example returns all the `Data` for a single user. From `user` variable you can access all user properties (e.g. `user.middlename`).

Comment: What if I still want to display other fields from the legacy database as well?

Comment: Can't do subqueries with queries on different DBs.                             I get this error.

Comment: I forgot Queryset are lazy. I added a `list()` to force the queryset to run (and to have a real list)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually specify multiple databases in your `settings.py` file and let different models use different databases. In the settings module, set `DATABASE_ROUTERS` to a tuple of objects with the four methods `db_for_read`, `db_for_write`, `allow_relation` and `allow_syncdb`. The first two methods take a model and return the database to use for that model. More info is available in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/multi-db/#topics-db-multi-db-routing), excellent as always.

I find this method superior to that of furnis, since you only have to configure this once, and not for every query. Your problem is exactly why the database routers exist.

Comment: maybe, but since the OP wants to read from both databases it may be complex to define `db_for_read` method. Basing on the information available the only way to do that is to check the class of the instance passed into hints, but you have to update the method (and to remember to do it) every time you add a new model class. This may also obfuscate the source of data somehow, e.g. doing the expected subquery you'll get the `Can't do subqueries with queries on different DBs` error mentioned by user2584372 without any evident reason.

Comment: I guess that no models will be added to the legacy database, so you could probably just hardcode the legacy models and then default to the new database.

Comment: Well, it depends. The "legacy" database is probably managed by another developer, and she may introduce changes in the schema. You may avoid defining `using('default')` and leave only the `using('legacy')` when needed (maybe only for a single model). I do not arrogate that my approach is superior, only more explicit (and this may be useful expecially for somebody that have not developed for multiple dbs or when debugging) and it is the only e.g. that allows you to copy an object from a database to another. It is probably the quickest to code, but it depends on how many queries do you have.